# IllegalStateException: OrcaSharedPreferences used before initialized when calling openActiveSession on Facebook SDK 3.5

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I've upgraded facebook SDK from 3.0 to 3.5. Testing on my devices was fine but I got these crash reports:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: OrcaSharedPreferences used before initialized
> 1at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1433)
> 2at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
> 3at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
> 4at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
> 5at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
> 6at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
> 7at com.facebook.Settings.getAttributionId(SourceFile:418)
> 8at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.getSessionEventsState(SourceFile:684)
> 9at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.logEvent(SourceFile:645)
> 10at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.logEvent(SourceFile:641)
> 11at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.logSdkEvent(SourceFile:537)
> 12at com.facebook.Session.logAuthorizationStart(SourceFile:1110)
> 13at com.facebook.Session.authorize(SourceFile:915)
> 14at com.facebook.Session.open(SourceFile:995)
> 15at com.facebook.Session.openForRead(SourceFile:388)
> 16at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(SourceFile:891)
> 17at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(SourceFile:830)
> ```

This happens when a user tries to log in to the app using facebook.

I read in: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Orca SharedPreferences used before initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873794/java-lang-illegalstateexception-orca-sharedpreferences-used-before-initialized/18976512#18976512)
That it might be a case where the user doesn't have facebook app installed on his phone, but I also tested this scenario on my phone and it just opens facebook web view for logging in as it should.

It sucks to upgrade an SDK to find new crashes on code that worked just fine. What can be the cause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got this as well by force stopping the Facebook app before launching our app (also on FB SDK 3.5)

Comment: I've upgraded the FB SDK to 3.5.2. I've checked the diffs and it looks like some of the issues encountered on field were solved. I'll update this post after publishing the update to verify if the issues are fixed.

Comment: Upgrading to 3.5.2 did solve the problem. Conclusion - don't install new FB SDK until it gets patched with fixes...